Can I get cell index using querySelectorAll?
I'm running a forEach loop using document.querySelectorAll(), and I need to get the index of each node. What would be the best way to do this?
function queryFunc(query, func){
    document.querySelectorAll(query).forEach(func);
};

queryFunc(".fooBar", function(e){
    //I need to return the index of the cell that called the function.
});


What exactly do you mean with ”index”?

Post a [mcve] please

index is always the second parameter in a forEach loop.
const elements = document.querySelectorAll('your-selector');

elements.forEach((element, index) => {
  console.log(`Element: ${element}, Index: ${index}`);
  // Your code here
});

Based on your edit, here is how you can call the index argument from the external function.
function queryFunc(query, func){
    document.querySelectorAll(query).forEach((element, index) => {
        func(element, index);
    });
};

queryFunc(".fooBar", function(e, index){
    console.log('Cell index: ' + index);
});


This would work, but I'm actually passing a separate function to the forEach loop. Is there a way I could call the index argument from an external function? I edited the post with an example.

I've added new code to address your new requirement @AustinGriner

A lot for me to dissect here. Thanks a lot!

You are welcome. You can look into callback functions.

You can use foreach second argument to obtain cell index in the array:
cellsArray.forEach((cell, index) => {
                   //...
                   console.log('Cell id: ', index)) }


This would work, but I'm actually passing a separate function to the forEach loop. Is there a way I could call the index argument from an external function? I edited the post with an example.

If you mean the cellIndex of an HTMLTableCellElement, you can simply use the cellIndex property:


document.querySelectorAll("td").forEach(td => console.log(td.cellIndex))
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>r1c1</td>
    <td>r1c2</td>
    <td>r1c3</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>r2c1</td>
    <td>r3c2</td>
    <td>r3c3</td>
   </tr>
</table>



